# Good Unit Tests when ReSharper bugs for null checks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the latest version of ReSharper installed and I am trying to write a Unit Test for my MVC controller. I need the Unit Test to:

> Ensure the ViewModel passed to the View is of the **correct type**.

So here is what I have at the moment:

```
public void Create_HasCorrectViewModelType()
{
    // arrange
    var controller = new DraftController(_draftFacade);
    // act
    var viewResult = controller.Create() as ViewResult;
    var viewModel = viewResult.Model as DraftViewModel;
    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(viewModel.GetType(), typeof(DraftViewModel));
}
```

I have issues with this, and would like to know your thoughts on the matter.

1. the arrange makes sense. I am arranging / setting up my controller.
2. Only the first line in the act seems logical to me. But me trying to grab the ViewModel isn't really an Act is it? Sounds like `// arrange` again!
3. ReSharper complains that I am not doing null checks on `viewResult` and `viewModel`.

[image: resharper null checks]

I can go with ReSharper's recommendation, then my test becomes:

```
public void Create_HasCorrectViewModelType()
{
    // arrange
    var controller = new DraftController(_draftFacade);
    // act
    var viewResult = controller.Create() as ViewResult;
    var viewModel = viewResult?.Model as DraftViewModel;
    // assert
    if (viewModel != null) Assert.IsInstanceOfType(viewModel.GetType(), typeof(DraftViewModel));
}
```

Now ReSharper is happy, but then my Unit Test don't seem clean anymore! I feel like there are too many paths that can be taken for that one unit test.

Anyone else bugged by this? What can I do to improve this? Or is this the best I'm going to get?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to do: `Assert.IsInstanceOf<DraftViewModel>(viewResult?.Model);` ?

Comment: Isn't that the same thing but written differently?

Comment: At the moment, you're creating a variable `viewModel` that's only going to be populated if `Model` is castable to a `DraftViewModel`.  Doing the same thing in your assert is redundant, you could just be asserting that `viewModel != null`.  In your refactored, 'resharper friendly' approach you're going to get a pass if `viewModel` is null, which feels wrong.  The approach I'm suggesting gets rid of the unnecessary variable and gives you a single line assert that confirms all of the expected linkages.  If you don't care about them, then ignore resharper, you know the context better than it does.

Comment: Can't you just assert that it's not null, AND assert it's the expected type as well? Definitely don't make the assert conditional on it not being null, else there is no assert and it passes when null.

Comment: This question might be more on-topic over at http://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/ . However, before posting please [follow their tour](http://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Asserting

> ```
> if (viewModel != null) Assert.IsInstanceOfType(viewModel.GetType(), typeof(DraftViewModel));
> ```

You should use another assert and not an `if`

```
Assert.IsNotNull(viewModel);
```

Resharper even suggests this option:

[image]

#### Test name

> ```
> Create_DraftFacade_ViewResultWithDraftViewModel
> ```

You might also want to reconsider the naming of your tests. Usually we use this pattern

> TestedMethod/Property_TestData/Case_ExpectedResult

Answer (score 1):

If `controller.Create()` is always creating ViewResult you must use explicit cast

```
var viewResult = (ViewResult)controller.Create();
```

else you must write another test for `controller.Create()`.

The assertion code `var viewModel = viewResult.Model as DraftViewModel;` are using `as`,  if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null so instead of `IsInstanceOfType` use `IsNotNUll`.

By the way, I can't get the act of your test by seeing your method name and I recommend you to read [this](https://dzone.com/articles/7-popular-unit-test-naming) article.